# Meaning of 'Did commercial travellers dash about in motorcars' in Dorothy L. Sayers story?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, dorothy-l-sayers

> "That is a very dreadful story," said the Padre.
>
> "Very," said I, "and there are some rather odd points about it. Did commercial travellers dash about in motorcars when Popper was a youngster? And why didn't he take that evidence straight to the police?"

---

The above is almost the last part of "Dilemma", short story written by Dorothy L. Sayers. The word 'dash about' seems to be a kind of twisting part of this short story, but I can't figure out the real meaning of this phrase.

Hoping somebody could help me.

Comment: In England we still dash about and dash around. You don't need a car: you can dash about on foot, or dash to the shops before they close. You could even dash off to Australia at a moment's notice. It's rather a middle-class expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important bit of this sentence is not “dash about”, but “motor-cars”. The point being that 
the character ‘Old Popper’ had introduced his tale with the claim that

> “The thing actually happened to me—years ago, many years ago. … It happened when I was quite a youngster, and was working as a clerk in a solicitor’s office.”

When would this have been? Well, ‘Dilemma’ was written for the ‘Short Story’ programme on BBC radio, and was broadcast on 6 April 1934*. So if Popper is in his sixties, say, then his youth would have been 40 years previously, that is, in the 1890s, when motor-cars were not yet widespread and cheap enough for commercial travellers to go about in them. This means that Popper’s tale must have been a fabrication.

* According to Robert B. Harmon and Margaret A. Burger (1977), [*An Annotated Guide to the Works of Dorothy L. Sayers*](https://archive.org/details/annotatedguideto0000harm/page/238), New York: Garland, p. 239.

Answer (score 4):

"Dash" can mean a lot of things, but I think here connotes mostly "movement", as if the question was "did commercial travelers go from place to place in motorcars?", with an added side-connotation of doing so stylishly.

I asked Google books for "dash about town" and came up with instances like this recent one (from
Juliet Clutton-Brock's 1992 *Horse*)

> In English spa towns in the early part of the 19th century, young gentlemen
>   would dash about town driving their latest status symbols, such as this
>   convertible model -- an elegant sporting phaeton driven with ...

that are consistent with Dash = Move.  But it carries a whiff  of a different connotation, of Dash = Style, or Dash = Panache, or Dash = Profligacy, as in this snippet from a 1817 play by Maria Edgeworth

> he and our Mr. Beauchamp will be cutting a fine dash 
>   about town, for this minor's to have a swinging allowance--- may play
>   away as he pleases...